# Is valueOf necessary here or is it just redundant?

Tags: typescript

```
const bearer: string = `Bearer ${accessToken}`.valueOf();
const tenantId: string = account.tenantId.valueOf();
const headers: Record<string, string> = {
  "Authorization": bearer,
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "TenantId": tenantId,
};
```

The config object I use for an axios get request requires the types of the strings to be primitives. Is it redundant to add valueOf()in this case since it auto casts it to a primitive?

Comment: What is `account.tenantId`?

Comment: This looks pretty easy to test but you can do without `valueOf()`, unless `tenantId` is coming as `new String("xyz")`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAV4PW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no undeclared/unimported types or values.